# Compare two json responses without values with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

Is that possible to compare two json responses with Jackson lib ignoring all values.

So below will assert both attribute and values.

```
{
    "employee":
    {
        "id": "1212",
        "fullName": "John Miles",
        "age": 34
    }
}
```

Code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
assertEquals(mapper.readTree(s1), mapper.readTree(s2));
```

Comment: In essence you want to only to know whether the objects have the same keys, i.e. the same structure. Is that correct?

Comment: @Turing85  exactly

Comment: I believe the description for what you want is to compare the _JSON object shapes_, and you need to specify whether the types of the values are included.

Comment: Search about Json Schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick lookup did not yield any results that Jackson has built-in capabilites for this functionality. We can, however, write our own checker for this task to compare two `Map<String, ?>`s in such a way that we return `true` [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if).:

- the `keySet()` of both `Map`s are equal
- the `keySet()` of those objects that are `instanceof Map` of both `Map`s are equal
- the values which are `Map`s must be structurally equally aswell (recursive call)

For the analysis, we have to make the assumption that if a `Map` is a value in another `Map`, it must be a `Map<String, ?>` since our solution will make an unchecked cast with this assumption.

With this assumption, a solution may look like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unhecked")
public static boolean areStructuralEqual(Map<String, ?> left, Map<String, ?> right) {
    if (!Objects.equals(left.keySet(), right.keySet())) {
        return false;
    }

    Set<String> leftKeysWithMapValues = extractAllKeysThatMapToMaps(left);
    Set<String> rightKeysWithMapValues = extractAllKeysThatMapToMaps(right);
    if (!Objects.equals(leftKeysWithMapValues, rightKeysWithMapValues)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (String key : leftKeysWithMapValues) {
        if (!areStructuralEqual(
                (Map<String, ?>) left.get(key),
                (Map<String, ?>) right.get(key))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static Set<String> extractAllKeysThatMapToMaps(Map<String, ?> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() instanceof Map)
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/KFyZ5G)

Notice that this solution does not verify that the types of the keys are the same. Also, if the value of a key is set to `null` in one `Map` and the key is not present in the other `Map`, the comparison will return `false`. The latter can be fixed by filtering out keys whose values are `null`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unhecked")
public static boolean areStructuralEqual(Map<String, ?> left, Map<String, ?> right) {
    Set<Entry<String, ?>> leftEntriesWithNonNullValues = 
            extractEntriesWithNonNullValues(left);
    Set<Entry<String, ?>> rightEntriesWithNonNullValues =
            extractEntriesWithNonNullValues(right);
    Set<String> leftKeysWithNonNullValues = leftEntriesWithNonNullValues.stream()
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    Set<String> rightKeysWithNonNullValues = rightEntriesWithNonNullValues.stream()
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    if (!Objects.equals(leftKeysWithNonNullValues, rightKeysWithNonNullValues)) {
        return false;
    }

    Set<String> leftKeysWithMapValues =
            extractAllKeysThatMapToMaps(leftEntriesWithNonNullValues);
    Set<String> rightKeysWithMapValues =
            extractAllKeysThatMapToMaps(rightEntriesWithNonNullValues);
    if (!Objects.equals(leftKeysWithMapValues, rightKeysWithMapValues)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (String key : leftKeysWithMapValues) {
        if (!areStructuralEqual(
                (Map<String, ?>) left.get(key),
                (Map<String, ?>) right.get(key))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static Set<String> extractAllKeysThatMapToMaps(Set<Entry<String, ?>> entrySet) {
    return entrySet.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() instanceof Map)
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
}

private static Set<Entry<String, ?>> extractEntriesWithNonNullValues(Map<String, ?> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> Objects.nonNull(e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ExiJYj)

Comment: Here both json responses (actual and expected) has to be pass as Map to your said method. Is that correct?